# Split MySQL 'TIME' field into separate parts

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to split a time entry into its 3 separate variables, ie:

```
07:15:20
```

to

```
$hour = 07
$minute = 15
$second = 20
```

I know it's a very basic question for most but I'm struggling a bit at the moment :)

Comment: just google php `explode` and you have your answer

Comment: @Class split function is deprecated. refer to http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$time = "07:15:20";
list($hour,$minute,$second) = explode(":", $time);
print $hour . " - " . $minute . " - " . $second; 
?>
```

Demo: http://3v4l.org/NWa8L

Answer (score 0):

easiest way I can think of

```
        <?php
        $time = "07:15:20";
        $time = explode(":",$time);
        $hour = $time[0];
        $minute = $time[1];
        $second = $time[2];
        ?>
```